# Enabling SSL with MySQL RDS in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect securely to RDS instance from Hibernate. Relevant properties in my hibernate.cfg file looks like this.

```
<property name="connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://<endpoint>/<db>?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUniCode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;useSSL=true     
</property>
<property name="dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect </property>    
<property name="connection.verifyServerCertificate">false</property>
<property name="connection.requireSSL">true</property>
```

But I am getting following exception.

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Do I need to configure something on my RDS instance as well?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this but don't know root cause yet.

Somehow adding these connection properties separately was not working but when I added them as parameters in connection URL, it worked.

```
 jdbc:mysql://<endpoint>/<db>?autoReconnect=true&useUniCode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=false&requireSSL=true
```